# Retrieving the currently authenticated user using OktaAuth from multiple angular components

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am new to Angular and currently working on an angular project that integrates with Okta and uses the @okta/okta-angular SDK.

In some secured components, I would like to retrieve the currently authenticated user. The SDK provides some useful APIs such as the below:

```
const userClaims = await oktaAuth.getUser();
```

My question is, would it be a good practice to inject the OktaAuth object in all components that need some information about the user, or is there some other mechanism?

Currently, this is basically what I am doing in secured components:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { OKTA_AUTH } from '@okta/okta-angular';
import { OktaAuth } from '@okta/okta-auth-js';

@Component({
...
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  email: string = '';
  constructor(
    private orderHistoryService: OrderHistoryService,
    @Inject(OKTA_AUTH) private oktaAuth: OktaAuth
  ) {}

  async ngOnInit() {
    const userClaims = await this.oktaAuth.getUser();
    this.email = userClaims.email as string;
    this.someFunction(); //assumes that the user is authenticated.
  }
```